# Problem with masquerade and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, bridge, firewalld

My host is Fedora 32 with firewalld enabling with masquerade. It has only a wifi network adapter.

I have a Debian Buster as a VirtualBox guest that has networking issues, for example, running apt-get or curl:

```
curl  -L -O https://github.com/theleagueof/junction/archive/master.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0    181      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   181
100 37924    0 37924    0     0  20757      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 45801
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

Whenever I disable *masquerade*  on firewalld from Fedora 32, Debian hasn't any issue.

This my firewalld configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlp2s0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns ssh
  ports: 1714-1764/tcp 1714-1794/tcp 1122/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I need masquerade because I have a few lxc containers. I don't understand if VirtualBox guest is bridged why is affected with masquerade enabled?

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it?